# Heroku push rejected, railties dependency conflict? Ruby on Rails Tutorial Section 1.4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Trying to push first_app to heroku.  Starts out looking like it's working OK, but after a few seconds, I get:

> Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
>   Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
>   In Gemfile:
>   rails (= 3.2.1) ruby depends on 
>   railties (= 3.2.1) ruby
>   sass-rails (= 3.2.3) ruby depends on
>   railties (3.2.2.rc1)

It goes on to tell me that it failed to install gems and the push was rejected.

My Gemfile is currently as specified in the tutorial, but I have tried fiddling with the explicit version numbers to see whether I could resolve the error that way: no luck.  I also tried doing a bundle update, which gave me a similar error, but straight out of Bundler, instead of from the Heroku push; and deleting the Gemfile.lock file, which caused other errors so confusing I wound up deleting everything and starting over.

Comment: Copy paste your Gemfile here please

Comment: My Gemfile (and please forgive the mess I've made of the line breakage): `source 'https://rubygems.org'`
`gem 'rails', '3.2.1'`
`group :development do`
`  gem 'sqlite3',  '1.3.5'`
`end`

`# Gems used only for assets and not required`
`# in production environments by default.`
`group :assets do`
`  gem 'sass-rails',  '3.2.3'`
`  gem 'coffee-rails',  '3.2.2'`
`  gem 'uglifier',  '1.0.3'`
`end`

`gem 'jquery-rails',  '2.0.0'`

Comment: Same problem, but none of the solutions here worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you have changes in group assets. Use it:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
end
```

Comment: That did the trick, but I'm left with questions.  First, my reading of the tutorial led me to believe that I was supposed to make those changes.  Did I miss some cue that I wasn't actually supposed to do so?  Second, is there some reason you suggest putting therubyracer in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the gem to sass-rails ~>3.2.4 and you would most likely have to update the jquery-rails to ~>2.0.1. Then run bundle before you push the app to heroku. bundle should tell you if there are further dependency conflicts.

Comment: I did try changing the version number for sass-rails to ~> 3.2.4 before I posted my plea for help.  I did not modify the jquery-rails version number though, and I found myself getting essentially the same error message out of Bundler.  Your solution may very well work just as well as ka8725's, but I'm trying to stick as close to the "Script" in the tutorial as possible.  (I did find, with further testing, that omitting version numbers entirely gave me a functional, push-able application too.)

Comment: @HiramQ.Pustule .. I agree with you. Even if this answer gave me a solution I am also trying to stick with the script provided in the tutorial. Plus this kind of problems may happen in the future and we should be able to know what to do in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is caused by running a different version of gem from the one in the tutorial. Run gem -v to find out the version you're running. He's using 1.8.24 in the tutorial. If the versions are different run gem update --system 1.8.24 to update. Then run bundle again and push the app to heroku.