# Why is my Heroku push rejected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through chapter 1 of [Hartl's Rails 4.0 tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0#sec-heroku_step_one), and I'm stuck on Section 1.4.2, which is to push a black app into GitHub and Heroku.

I tried typing `git push heroku master`, but I get an error message, similar to a previous question on StackOverFlow:

- [Heroku push rejected - Hartl's Rails 3.2 tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668675/heroku-push-rejected-hartls-rails-3-2-tutorial)
- [Heroku push rejected, railties dependency conflict? Ruby on Rails Tutorial Section 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490878/heroku-push-rejected-railties-dependency-conflict-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-secti)

It's probably the same but I don't even realize it:

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using 
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

Here is the Gemfile I used:

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
end
```

---

**UPDATE**: The main error seems to be `/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory`  Is that folder on the Heroku machine or my home computer ?

I tried removing the line `ruby '1.9.3'` from my `.gitignore` but it still returns this message.

Comment: Your Gemfile specifies Ruby 1.9.3, but from the message returned by Heroku it looks like it's using Ruby 1.9.1. Not sure if that's related to the problem

Comment: That should not be an issue, I've used ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 using the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

First, Remove `ruby 1.9.3` from the `Gemfile`. You don't need it and may be the cause of your problem. Start of your `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
end

etc........
```

Also, make sure you run

```
bundle install --without production
```

since you are using `sqlite3` in `:development` and `postgresql` in `:production`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The issue is that Bundler is generating stubs. Rails 4 apps do not store stubs in the app's bin/ directory. In order to fix this problem you need to use the following commands:

```
$ bundle config --delete bin
```

Then you need to update the bin directory to use the new Rails 4 executables

```
$ rake rails:update:bin
```

Then add the new bin/ directory to your version control using:

```
$ git add bin
```

Commit the changes and push your code to Heroku

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and the problem was that i didn't chose the version of ruby that i want to use, so i did the following:

```
$rvm list
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ i686 ]

$rvm use  ruby-1.9.3-p392

$rvm list 
    =>   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ i686 ]
    ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ i686 ]
```